# Can i return a condtional Statement in React?

Tags: reactjs

I want the input element to be hidden  when device ==="Mobile" but I need to refresh the page to see the effect, why?

```
export default function Input() {
const [device,setDevice]=useState("");
function setDeviceWidth(width){
    if(width>567){
        return setDevice("noMobile");
    }
    else{
        return setDevice("Mobile");
    }
}  

useEffect(()=>{
    setDeviceWidth(window.innerWidth);
  
})
     
    
 return(
<div>
    {device==="Mobile"?<div></div>:<input type="text"/>}
</div>
 )
}
```

Comment: `Mobile` is not equals with `mobile`, try as `device === "Mobile"`. Probably just a typo.

Comment: How ever i need to refresh the page to see the effect,why?

Comment: Because useEffect runs exactly at the moment after the component has rerendered. Resizing the window will not rerun the effect.

Comment: What should i do for that?

Comment: You have missed the dependency array after the UseEffect..:-)

Comment: If you are testing this on Chrome on PC you need to inspect first to mobile view and then render the component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your component only reads the window width on mounting.
I suggest you listen to the window resize event:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        const listener = () => setDeviceWidth(window.innerWidth); // keep a reference to the listener
        window.addEventListener("resize", listener); // attach it to the resize event
        return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", listener); // detach it on unmounting
    }, []); // only run on mounting and unmounting
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const [device,setDevice]=useState("");
const [deviceWidth, setDeviceWidth] = useState(0)

// every time when you resize the window 
// it will be recalculate the `deviceWidth` and  `device`
useEffect(()=>{
  const handler = () => setDeviceWidth(window.innerWidth);
  window.addEventListener('resize', handler)
  return ()=>{
    // next time remove previous listener
    window.removeEventListener('resize', handler)
  }
})

useEffect(()=>{
  if(deviceWidth > 567){
      setDevice("noMobile")
   } else {
      etDevice("Mobile")
   }
},[deviceWidth])
```